# Ajax Update Panel asp.net trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have 3 update panel control asp.net which `updatePanel1`, `updatePanel2`, `updatePanel3`. When page load first `updatePanel1` will automatically load more `buttons` ex: `button1`. When click `button1` in `updatePanel1`, that will show buttons in `updatePanel2` ex: `button2`. When click `button2` it will trigger`updatePanel3` and show data in `updatePanel3` like gridview.

Now, what is my problem is when click `button2` all buttons in `updatePanel2` lose. can you give me solution why I lose buttons in `updatePanel2`?

`UPDATE`

`Default.cs`

> ```
>     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>
>
>         foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> catshow in cat)
>         {
>             Button x = new Button();
>             x.ID = catshow.Key;
>             x.CssClass = "btnTop";
>             x.Text = catshow.Value;
>             x.CommandArgument = catshow.Key;
>             x.Command += new CommandEventHandler(buttonClick);
>
>             PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(x);
>         }
>
>
>     }
>
>     protected void buttonClick(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
>     {
>         string key = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
>         foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String> datshow in data[key])
>         {
>             Button x = new Button();
>             x.ID = datshow.Key;
>             x.CssClass = "btnBottom";
>             x.Text = datshow.Value;
>             x.CommandArgument = datshow.Key;
>             x.Command += new CommandEventHandler(buttonClickPrd);
>
>             PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(x);
>         }
>     }
>
>
>     protected void buttonClickPrd(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
>     {
>         string key = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
>         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>         dt.Columns.Add("Qty", Type.GetType("System.String"));
>         dt.Columns.Add("Unit", Type.GetType("System.String"));
>         dt.Columns.Add("Price", Type.GetType("System.String"));
>         dt.Columns.Add("Total", Type.GetType("System.String"));
>         dt.Rows.Add();
>         dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Qty"] = this.sales[key]["qty"];
>         dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Unit"] = this.sales[key]["unit"];
>         dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Price"] = this.sales[key]["price"];
>         dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Total"] = this.sales[key]["total"];
>         GridView1.DataSource = dt;
>         GridView1.DataBind();
>     }
> ```

`Default.aspx`

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
             </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
         <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
                 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
             </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

this has to do with the viewstate. since buttons in updatepanel2 are created at runtime, they get lost is page_load event. You will have to regenerate each time. Exactly how you will implement it depends upon how you have written you code. without code I cant tell you more.

Comment: hi @ratna, thanks here I already update my question, yes you right i use button programaticaly and how I use view state?